# send whole table in FCM notification from server

Tags: push-notification, server, notifications

I want to send the whole table in FCM notification from the server.

```
to = regId,
notification = new
{
    body = "Your Guest Order Placed Successfull! Order ID is : "+order.OrderID+
    "\n Total Bill : "+order.TotalBill+
    "\nMenus are:\n"
   + db.Tbl_OrderMenu.Where(t => t.OrderID == order.OrderID).Select(t=>t.Tbl_Menu.MenuName && t.Tbl_Menu.Price).FirstOrDefault(),
    title = "Canteen App",
    sound = "Disabled"
}
```

Here I able to send only first record.

I want the whole table.
I think i should use **foreach loop**, but i have no idea about how to use **Foreach** here.

Please suggest proper code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, take the data in variable

```
var m = (from menu in db.Tbl_OrderMenu
           where
           menu.OrderID == order.OrderID
           select new
           {
                 menu.Tbl_Menu.MenuName,
                 menu.Quantity,
                 menu.Amount
           });
```

then, append data in StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (var item in m)
                    {                      
                        sb.Append(item.MenuName);
                        sb.Append(":\t");
                        sb.Append(item.Quantity);
                        sb.Append("(Nos)\t");
                        sb.Append(item.Amount);
                        sb.Append("(Rs)\n");
                    }
```

Then Finally, send StringBuilder object to notification Body

```
var data = new
           {
              to = regId,
              notification = new
              {
                  body = "Your  Order Placed Successfull!"+
                  "\nTotal Bill : " + order.TotalBill +
                  "\nMenus are:\n"
                  + sb,
                  title = "Canteen App",
                  sound = "Disabled"
              }

           };
```